# Android Emulator Render Issue - After macOS Big Sur Update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, macos-big-sur

**After the macOS Big Sur, `11.0.1` update, the Android emulator began to display image rendering issues.**

## Issue

The emulator display window is repeating the device image. An [*issue*](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173282117) has been documented in Android's IssueTracker.

**Conditions**

1. Re-sizing: When the emulator window is resized, increased or decreased
2. Orientation change: Portrait to landscape, and vice-versa

[image]
[image]

## Attempted Solutions

- Clear the emulator with *Wipe Data* from the *Android Device Manager*.
- Create a new emulator instance.

## Configuration

**Android Studio**

- Android Studio 4.1.1
- Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.6953283, built on November 4, 2020
- Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS 10.16
- GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
- Memory: 1979M
- Cores: 16
- Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
  Non-Bundled Plugins: com.android.tool.sizereduction.plugin, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, cn.wjdghd.unique.plugin.id, mobi.hsz.idea.gitignore, com.developerphil.adbidea

**Emulator**

- Name: Pixel_3a_API_29
- CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)
- Path: /Users/adamhurwitz/.android/avd/Pixel_3a_API_29.avd
- Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 29)
- Skin: 1080x2220
- SD Card: 512M
- fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile:
- runtime.network.speed: full
- hw.accelerometer: yes
- hw.device.name: pixel_3a
- hw.lcd.width: 1080
- hw.initialOrientation: Portrait
- image.androidVersion.api: 29
- tag.id: google_apis_playstore
- hw.mainKeys: no
- hw.camera.front: emulated
- avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 3a API 29
- hw.gpu.mode: auto
- hw.ramSize: 1536
- PlayStore.enabled: true
- fastboot.forceColdBoot: no
- hw.cpu.ncore: 4
- hw.keyboard: yes
- hw.sensors.proximity: yes
- hw.dPad: no
- hw.lcd.height: 2220
- vm.heapSize: 256
- skin.dynamic: yes
- hw.device.manufacturer: Google
- hw.gps: yes
- skin.path.backup: _no_skin
- hw.audioInput: yes
- image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-29/google_apis_playstore/x86/
- showDeviceFrame: no
- hw.camera.back: virtualscene
- AvdId: Pixel_3a_API_29
- hw.lcd.density: 440
- hw.arc: false
- hw.device.hash2: MD5:0e6953ebf01bdc6b33a2f54746629c50
- fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no
- fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes
- hw.trackBall: no
- hw.battery: yes
- hw.sdCard: yes
- tag.display: Google Play
- runtime.network.latency: none
- disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944
- hw.sensors.orientation: yes
- avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8
- hw.gpu.enabled: yes

Comment: The same issue for me

Comment: It's a bug in emulator (or Big Sur, I'm not sure :) ). https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173282117

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug with Android Studio 4.1.1 as well. This issue appeared along with installing the latest versions of Android Studio and macOS. It is hard to tell which is the cause.

Comment: Everyone should star the *[issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173282117)* @SergeyGlotov linked to in order to help highlight the issue in Android's IssueTracker.

Comment: I have two external monitors hooked up via USB hub and I just get a gray rectangle on both of those screens. MacBook screen is fine. I tried all the tricks here and none of them worked. I did STAR issue in IssueTracker. All was fine before Big Sur update. Latest tools all being used and I did create a new emulator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that upgrading android studio (4.1.2), the emulator, and SDK tools fixes the issue since 2021.

After updating Android Studio, go to the preferences for Android Studio > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools (tab) and select Android Emulator (I used 30.3.5), Android SDK Tools (26.1.1), and maybe the Android SDK Build-tools.

*Disclaimer: These steps solved it for me. It might well be that only updating the "Android Emulator" SDK tool would have been enough.*

Comment: Worked for me! This should be the accepted answer since it is not just a workaround.

Comment: Worked for me as well. So this is the permanent solution.

Answer (score 28):

I am having the same problem, after upgrade for Big Sur.

I find out a workaround... after resize, click twice on magnifying glass.

On some emulators this don't work. In this cases try Settings/Show window frame around device - turn off/turn on. This works for me.

[image]

Comment: I also have this problem when I rotate the device after upgrading to Big Sur, clicking the magnifying glass works for me.

Comment: As this answer says, a temporary solution for me is was to press the zoom option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0clV0.png

Comment: seems this workaround is always working on my MacBook, thank you for sharing!

Comment: cmd+Z will save you having to click the "magnifying class"

Answer (score 22):

I think I have found a temporary solution.
If you are using another monitor with your computer just move the emulator between displays after resizing it. It is adjusting itself in this way

Answer (score 5):

A simple workaroud is to just hide and show it again.

[image]

Comment: this worked for me. Thank you for the solution

Comment: to the top! most effective answer

Answer (score 1):

only way I have found so far is to resize emulator to wanted size -> go to emulator settings -> Displays -> add secondary display -> apply changes -> remove secondary display -> apply changes

kinda sucks, but it is what it is for now

[image: screenshot of emulator settings]

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix:

After rotate:

- Click in the "Enter zoom mode" (CMD+Z).

This will force layout and render of the screen.

Comment: And don't forget to do "CMD+Z" again to leave zoom mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I was having a folder `Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager_2` with this "_2" at the end, which SDK tools installer reported as an anomaly.

```
/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager_2
```

I deleted this folder with "_2" at the end and restarted the android studio. Emulators are showing up now.